# environment variable in ubuntu

Tags: python, bash, environment-variables, ubuntu-14.04

I'm trying to install the python module 'Pycpx' but I'm getting an error that it can't find an environment variable

[Pycpx](http://www.stat.washington.edu/~hoytak/code/pycpx/download.html)

> Exception: CPLEX concert include directory not found: please set
>   environment variable CPLEX_PATH to point to the base of the
>   CPlex/Concert installation. Attempting to find files:
>   ilconcert/iloexpression.h, ilconcert/iloalg.h, ilconcert/iloenv.h,
>   ilconcert/ilosolution.h.

I create a file called .bash_profile in my home directory and I put this line in it which points to the folder where these header files are located.

```
CPLEX_PATH = /home/joe/concert/include/ilconcert
```

Is this the correct way to add environment variables as I am still getting the error?

I get this error whether  I install with `easy_install pycpx` or I get the source tarball from here [tarball](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/pycpx/) and run `python setup.py install`.

Many thanks

Comment: Are you using a virtualenv?

Comment: you should omit the spaces around '='

Answer (score 3):

The correct way of doing it is as follows:

```
export CPLEX_PATH=/home/joe/concert/include/ilconcert
```

Answer (score 1):

No, that's not right. You can't have those spaces around the `=` sign, and you should `export` the variable, like this:

```
export CPLEX_PATH=/home/joe/concert/include/ilconcert
```